# Reading HTTP cookies from adobe Air desktop app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, cookies, air

I am developing an Adobe AIR app where I need to read the session id from the cookie of a http request.

I have found a method called `URLRequest.manageCookies` supported by AIR so I hope there should be a way to read the cookies as well. I am using AIR 3.

I want to read **HTTP** cookies **not Local Shared Objects** and in a desktop AIR application.